# Invalid Identifier error with Inner Join query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT adm.*
  FROM adm_bucket ab
 INNER JOIN lms_user_role_mapping urm ON urm.bucket_id = ab.bucket_id
 INNER JOIN lms_roles_privilege_mapping rpm ON rpm.role_id = urm.role_id
 WHERE urm.user_id =19375 
   AND ab.bucket_OWNER=19375;
```

---error

```
ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_003"."ROLE_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 220
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have not defined a alias named as **adm** for any table, i think thats the problem, either make it ab.* or urm.* or rpm.* according to your desired result.

```
SELECT adm.*
  FROM adm_bucket ab
 INNER JOIN lms_user_role_mapping urm ON urm.bucket_id = ab.bucket_id
 INNER JOIN lms_roles_privilege_mapping rpm ON rpm.role_id = urm.role_id
 WHERE urm.user_id =19375 
   AND ab.bucket_OWNER=19375;
```